# Cloud Run stuck in a loop

Tags: python, if-statement, cloud, httprequest, google-cloud-run

In short, i have a Cloud Run a Python app that checks the file format as follows:

```
 if not(object_id.endswith('.csv') or object_id.endswith(".json")):
        msg = "Wrong file format!"
        logging.error(f"Bad Request. error: {msg}")
        return (f"Bad Request: {msg}", 400)
    else:
        msg = "JSON or CSV format detected."
        logging.info(f"Correct format: {msg}")
```

When i test this locally by triggering it with Postman using the wrong file format (on purpose), i get the expected error "Bad Request" and the app stops.

But when i test it in Cloud Run, i keep getting the error 400. It doesnt exit the function it keeps retrying. Can anyone spot what i have done wrong?

I just included this code snippet as this is where the error message comes from.

I tried changing the HTTP codes between 405 and 400 as the documentation states that the containers react differently. But nothing has worked.